# No option to change project facet in Eclipse Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am running Eclipse 3.8 on linux, and trying to follow [this tutorial](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/resteasy/resteasy-hello-world-example/) to get my first Maven project up and running. However when I get to the step that says "Change the project facet" Im at a loss.... there doesn't seem to be a "Project Facets" option. What did I do wrong?

[image]

Comment: When I try to install it I get: `"m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse" will be ignored because it is already installed.`

Comment: dang it- solved it- I needed the Java EE Tools. Select Juno as the url, go down to web XML, and check the Eclipse Java web dev tools

Comment: Juno was released in 2012. Grab some Oxygen.

Comment: Better get more recent version of Eclipse...